# Trying to add an event listener for PLAYING/PAUSED_STATE_ENTERED, returning error 1119

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6, flash-player-11

Basically I have a very simple video gallery set up. I want it so that when the video is paused some buttons will become visible on the screen and when it is playing these buttons will not be visible. This is my code:

```
import fl.video.*;
import fl.video.VideoEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

videoOne.addEventListener(Event.PLAYING_STATE_ENTERED, hideInfo());
videoOne.addEventListener(Event.PAUSED_STATE_ENTERED, showInfo());

function showInfo() {
    thumbnailOne.visible = true;
    thumbnailTwo.visible = true;
    thumbnailThree.visible = true;
    videoGalleryInfo.visible = true;
    infoHidden = 0;
}

function hideInfo() {
    thumbnailOne.visible = false;
    thumbnailTwo.visible = false;
    thumbnailThree.visible = false;
    videoGalleryInfo.visible = false;
    infoHidden = 1;
}
```

I have tried using Event instead of VideoEvent and so on as this fixed an issue with adding another event listener earlier on for the COMPLETE event, but I'm always returned with

```
Video gallery, Layer 'ActionScript', Frame 77, Line 22  1119: Access of possibly undefined property PLAYING_STATE_ENTERED through a reference with static type Class.

Video gallery, Layer 'ActionScript', Frame 77, Line 23  1119: Access of possibly undefined property PAUSED_STATE_ENTERED through a reference with static type Class.
```

I do not understand what I'm doing wrong. Shouldn't the properties be defined through importing fl.video.*; and flash.events.Event;?

EDIT: In case it matters, here is the rest of my code for this particular scene, including the fixes that null suggested. I still get the same errors, plus a "1136: Incorrect number of arguments. Expected 1" error

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import fl.video.*;
import fl.video.VideoEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

stop();

homeButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, homePressed);
soundButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, soundPressed);
helpButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, helpPressed);
exitButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, exitPressed);

var videoPlaying:int = 0;
var infoHidden:int = 0;

videoOne.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, vid1Comp);
function vid1Comp(event:Event) {
    videoOne.visible = false;
    showInfo();
}



videoOne.addEventListener(VideoEvent.PLAYING_STATE_ENTERED, hideInfo);
videoOne.addEventListener(VideoEvent.PAUSED_STATE_ENTERED, showInfo);

function showInfo(e:Event):void {
    thumbnailOne.visible = true;
    thumbnailTwo.visible = true;
    thumbnailThree.visible = true;
    videoGalleryInfo.visible = true;
    infoHidden = 0;
}

function hideInfo(e:Event):void {
    thumbnailOne.visible = false;
    thumbnailTwo.visible = false;
    thumbnailThree.visible = false;
    videoGalleryInfo.visible = false;
    infoHidden = 1;
}

thumbnailOne.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playVid1);
function playVid1(event:MouseEvent) {
    hideInfo();

    if (musicPlaying == 1) {
        SoundMixer.stopAll();
        musicPlaying = 0;
    }

    videoOne.visible = true;
    videoOne.play();
    videoPlaying = 1;
}

videoOne.visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that to fix this issue you have to use the full path for the event, so changing

```
videoOne.addEventListener(VideoEvent.PLAYING_STATE_ENTERED, hideInfo);
videoOne.addEventListener(VideoEvent.PAUSED_STATE_ENTERED, showInfo);
```

to

```
videoOne.addEventListener(fl.video.VideoEvent.PLAYING_STATE_ENTERED, hideInfo);
videoOne.addEventListener(fl.video.VideoEvent.PAUSED_STATE_ENTERED, showInfo);
```

fixed it. Pretty simple, really. Thank you for your help regardless, @null.

Answer (score 0):

This line calls the function `hideInfo`:

```
videoOne.addEventListener(Event.PLAYING_STATE_ENTERED, hideInfo());
```

but it should instead pass the function (and not call it) like so:

```
videoOne.addEventListener(Event.PLAYING_STATE_ENTERED, hideInfo);
```

The constants for the type of event that you are adding are defined in the [`VideoEvent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/VideoEvent.html) class, so the actual code should look like this:

```
videoOne.addEventListener(VideoEvent.PLAYING_STATE_ENTERED, hideInfo);
```

The signature of the function should be that of a callback. It should take a single parameter of type `Event` or appropriate subclass thereof:

```
function hideInfo(e:Event):void {
```

You could also do

```
function hideInfo(e:VideEvent):void {
```

But you have no use for the parameter anyway, so there's' no real point in specializing the type further unnecessarily.

---

> I still get the same errors, plus a "1136: Incorrect number of arguments. Expected 1" error

That's because you changed the signature of the function as I suggested.
As you call your functions without any arguments:

```
showInfo();
```

This causes the error that you receive.

In order to avoid that and **because you are not making any use of the parameter in those functions** you can change the function once again to accept a default value of `null` for the parameter:

```
function showInfo(e:Event = null):void {
```

This way if called without a parameter the parameter defaults to `null`, which is ok, because you don't need the parameter anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I've tried changing my code to how you described but it has only given me more errors on the lines where I declare the hideInfo and showInfo functions. Passing the function did not fix the 1119 error either. It's almost as if it doesn't like me trying to listen for the event that the playing or paused state is triggered, and I had a similar issue as I mentioned with COMPLETE. I don't know if the fl.video class is just incredibly buggy or something because I've had no issues such as this until I've tried to use it.

Comment: @Trekkx your edit added a lot of code that wasn't there before. I addressed the issues in an edit of my answer, please check if that solves the problem.

Comment: I changed my functions so that they have the e:Event = null, which fixed the 1136 error. I'm still basically where I started though as I still get 1119 errors where I call PLAYING_STATE_ENTERED and PAUSED_STATE_ENTERED. Is there a solution to this problem, or a possible workaround so that I can achieve similar functionality without using those two constants? Thanks for your help so far by the way, and sorry to be a nuisance.